# Increase information density in the new gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm looking for a way to raise the information density in the new gmail (desktop version) without decreasing the font size.

(The new gmail has irresponsible use of whitespace and sidebar space, so that less text is visible in the same amount of screen real estate, than in the old gmail, despite having my display density set to "compact".)

So far, I've tried using AdBlock, but it turns out that the witespace is in the same page elements as important information, so it can't be blocked.